# Pandas conditional: How to use an If or While statement with str contains

Tags: python, pandas

How can I perform a conditional statement whilst using `str.contains()` in a pandas dataframe.

For example, I have a dataframe, with column `A` that contains the words `John has a Baseball`, `Amy has a Basketball`, `Sarah has a Tennis Racket` and `Alex has a Football`.

I want to do:

```
if df[df['A].str.contains('Ball')]
```

then extract the name string from sentences containing `Ball` & assign it to a new column `Name`

The desired result is for the new 'Name' column to contain: John, Amy & Alex

My actual code is as follows:

```
    if df[df['A'].str.contains('Anon')] == 'True':
        df['Name'] = df['A'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

This gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['True'] with block values
```

I have also tried:

```
     if df[df['A'].str.contains('Anon')] == True:
        df['Name'] = df['A'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

This gives me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `df['Name'] = np.where(df['A'].str.contains('Anon'), df['A'].str.split(' ').str[0], None)`

Comment: To add case insensitivity to @AmiTavory's comment, change the first arg of the `np.where` to `df['A'].str.lower().str.contains('ball')`

Comment: Thanks, this has cleared this up for me!!